# CSS jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, jquery-pagination

I have a table with data and the rows are classed .paginate, these are going to be paginated with a jquery script. There are two lines of code which are messing up my CSS and all the < td > are appearing in the first column of the table rather than being spread evenly. This is the jQuery code messing things up. Both lines are needed.

```
//hide all the elements inside content div
$('.paginate').css('display', 'none');

//and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
$('.paginate').slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: `$('.paginate).slice` What are you hoping to accomplish with this. I don't think that word means what you think it does.

Comment: @Leeish: What makes you say that? Seems to do exactly what the comment above expects it to do. What throws me about the question is the bit about `td` elements, though.

Comment: I guess I am confused when reading it without the full context of the situation.

Comment: @ Pierce: What does your markup look like? What kind of elements are the ones with the `paginate` class? Why control the `display` style directly rather than using `show` and `hide`?

Comment: The 1st row is the column names so they need to stay, the following rows are taken from a db with php and echoed out. I added a class .paginate so the jquery script would only do the pagination on those returned results

Comment: @PierceMcGeough: Again: What kind of elements have that class? You're not giving us anything like enough to work with here.

Comment: Sorry, the class is applied to each of the rows after the title rows. Its the rows that are to be paginated, and that works fine but the CSS is moving all the td of each row to the first column of the row its in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a class like this:

**CSS**

```
.displayNone {
    display: none;
}
```

And removing the class as needed

**JS**

```
$('.paginate').addClass('displayNone');

$('.paginate').slice(0, show_per_page).removeClass('displayNone');
```

Comment: Which is great, but irrelevant.